# custom google map is not rendering correctly, bad resolution

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have set a size for a custom google map icon to use it .

```
var icon_custom = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                                                "img/map/po_test.png" ,
                                                null,
                                                null,
                                                null,
                                                new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
                                                );
      marker_points = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(5.318590,-4.027873),
                                            map: map,
                                            title: " test ",
                                            icon: icon_custom,

                                    });
```

this size is identical to pixel size of `po_test.png` which is 50x50 px.
I'm having a very bad resolution displayed of those markers. and I don't know the reason of the problem .
this is the style of my the div where the google map is rendered

```
#map_point {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have added below to this question an example of the icon and the what I have as rendered in the google map .
[image: po_test.png example]
[image: google map render]

can you see the differences ? I have changed the size property and resized proportionally . the problem still remain .

Comment: The MarkerImage class is deprecated, use [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate this using your image `https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEqhc.png` on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5avewvj3/)....

And tell me what are the difference between the following 2 pictures...

[image]

[image]

The answer is... 
first pic is cap when the browser is in the retina monitor,
second pic is cap when the browser is in a dumb dell monitor. 
(same computer, same browser, I just slice it over, and reload.)

clearly there are something going on with all the scaling thing.. and I guess.. it takes more than setting to fix this issue.
May be you should report a bug, however, it would takes a long time for the Maps team to fix since it sounds like a very, very low priority bug to them.

Hope this help